# ¿Por que scale de CSS hace que redimesionar un div falle?

Tags: javascript, css

estoy escribiendo un programa en el cual existe un `div` que actúa como página de dibujo, esta pagina debe poder dimensionarse, acercase y alejarse, esto último usando `scale` de `CSS`, sin embargo, cuando se hace `zoom-out` en la página y se redimensiona, ocurre algo extraño.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo del código que tengo:

```js
//Mediante javascript, le damos el tamaño a la pagina

var box = document.getElementById('design_space'),
    page = document.getElementById('page'),
    resizer = document.getElementById('right_resizer'),
    ObjectResizer;
    
    
    
function init(){
    set_page_size(300, 100);
    set_page_position((box.offsetWidth / 2) - (page.offsetWidth / 2), (box.offsetHeight / 2) - (page.offsetHeight / 2));
    
    //Creamos la tira redimensionadora
    ObjectResizer = new Resizer(box, page);
    
    var current_scale = 1, min_scale = .3, max_scale = 4,
        default_scale = 1;
    box.addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        current_scale += event.deltaY * -0.01;

        current_scale = Math.min(Math.max(min_scale, current_scale), max_scale);
        
        current_scale = (current_scale === 1.36 || current_scale === 1.3499999999999992) ? default_scale : current_scale ;

        page.style.transform = 'scale(' + current_scale + ')';
        
        on_scale( event );
    }, false);
}    
    
function set_page_size(width, height){
    //Definimos el tamaño de la pagina.
    page.style.width = width + 'px';
    page.style.height = height + 'px';
}
function set_page_position(x, y){
    page.style.left = x + 'px';
    page.style.top = y + 'px';
}
function Resizer(container, target){
    var strip = document.createElement('section');
    strip.className = 'resize_strip';
    
    //Definimos el tamaño
    strip.style.height = target.offsetHeight + 'px';
    strip.style.top = target.offsetTop + 'px';
    strip.style.left = (target.offsetLeft + target.offsetWidth) + 'px';
    
    //Insertamos el elemento en el contenedor
    container.appendChild( strip );
    
    var x, resize = false, original_width;
    //Definimos los eventos
    strip.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
        x = target.offsetLeft;
        original_width = target.offsetWidth;
        resize = true;
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
        if(resize === true){
            target.style.width = (event.clientX - x) + 'px';
            strip.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
        }
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
        if(resize === true){
            resize = false;
        }
    }, false);
    
    
    this.setX = function(x){
        strip.style.left = x + 'px';
    }
    this.setY = function(y){
        strip.style.top = y + 'px';
    }
    this.setHeight = function(h){
        strip.style.height = h + 'px';
    }
}

function on_scale(event){
    //Actualizamos el tamaño de la barra redimsionadora
    var page_bounding_client_rect = page.getBoundingClientRect();
    ObjectResizer.setHeight( page_bounding_client_rect.height );
    ObjectResizer.setY( page_bounding_client_rect.y );
    ObjectResizer.setX( page_bounding_client_rect.x + page_bounding_client_rect.width );
}


init();
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
}
.box{
    border: 1px dotted #f00;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.page{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 13px #eee, -1px -1px 13px #eee;
}
.resize_strip{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-right: 5px solid #aaa;
    cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<section id="design_space" class="box">
    <section id="page" class="page">
    </section>
</section>
```

El detalle que no he podido resolver es cuando se hace `zoom-out` o `zoom-in`, el elemento que permite redimensionar la página no se posiciona correctamente en el borde de la página, he investigado y por lo que he leído, esto se debe al uso de la función `scale`.

**Nota: En el ejemplo, el elemento redimensionador en ocasiones no se coloca en la misma altura que la página, ese detalle no es importante.**

¿Como puedo corregir esta situación?